# Validating URL | Form not submitting?

Tags: javascript

Currently in my form, I have a type=text, but am trying to only accept a url in the certain component of the form.

I have tried multiple different regular expressions I found online, but it could also just be the way I am doing it. Right now, my form will not even submit. Any advice is helpful.

Note: https:// , http:// are both acceptable. When a valid url is not submitted, I want to throw my error message in the HTML.

HTML Form:

```
<form method="POST" id="Submit">
                <div class="inner-form">
                    <div class="input-field first-wrap">
                        <div class="svg-wrapper">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                      <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z "></path>
                  </svg>
                        </div>
                        <input id="search" type="text" name="url" placeholder="Paste domain" required/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field second-wrap">
                        <button id="button" class="btn-search" onclick="searchIt()" value="press" type="submit">SEARCH       </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <p id="errorMessage">Yikes! That's not a valid URL. .</p>

            </form>
```

Javascript:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const p = document.querySelector("p");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const regex = /^((https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()!@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)/;

    let progress = 0;
        const maxTime = 5000; // 5 seconds
        let interval = null;
    
        let form = document.querySelector('form')
    
            function searchIt() {
    
                let form = document.querySelector('form')
                console.log(form)
    
                form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
                 // onclick or the event that start the call
                    interval = setInterval(() => {
                    progress = progress >= 100 ? 100 : progress + 1
                    document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = `${progress}%`
    
    
                // end interval and wait at 100%
                    if(progress == 100) clearInterval(interval);
                    }, maxTime/100)
                    document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = ""
                    e.preventDefault()
                    let urlIN = form.url.value
                    let url = encodeURIComponent(urlIN)
                    console.log(url)
                    try {
                        const data = await fetch('/result', {
                            method: 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            body: JSON.stringify({
                                url: url
                            })
                        }).then(res => {
                            //document.open()
                            res.text().then(function(text) {
                                 console.log(text);   
                                //document.write(text)
                                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;
                                // Hide the progressbar, stop the timer and reset progress
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            progress = 0;
                            document.getElementById('myprogress').style.width = "0%"
                            document.getElementById('loadingcontainer').style.display = "none";
        
                            });
    
                        })
    
    
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                    }
    
                })
    
    
    
            }})
```

Currently, error in my console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: searchIt is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? If so, [edit] your question to add them. Otherwise, I suggest setting a breakpoint in your JavaScript code and step through with the debugger to see what is happening. See [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some general debugging tips.

Comment: Done. my onsubmit function is then undefined, but I am lost at how else I can structure this to validate my regex without throwing the custom validation

Comment: There is always the input type `url` included in `HTML:5` as well.

Comment: @dalelandry But it is the standard validation message I want to avoid. I just want to throw my error message.

Comment: What do you mean "done"? Is this in response to my message or one that was deleted?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i added the error to the question... that is what I mean by Done

Comment: @KyleUSA I do not see the whole HTML file. Without it I can only suggest checking where are you loading the JS file. Hopefully at the bottom of the page. Second idea that your function declaration is nested and is not available outside of the event listener callback. I would go ahead and declare it outside or if you don't want to mess around with the code I will paste you an example

Comment: The JS is in a script tag after my HTML. An example/answer would be helpful. Thanks @ADProgress

Comment: `function searchIt() {` This needs to be defined outside of the event handler for it to be accessible to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to validate if someone is entering a valid URL a much simpler way where you won't have to write so much code will be simply using the input type URL have a look at an example below:

```
<label for="url">Enter an https:// URL:</label>

<input type="url" name="url" id="url"
       placeholder="https://example.com"
       pattern="https://.*" size="30"
       required>
```

Link the Web Developer docs of [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url)

Comment: Were you able to render the error message?>

Comment: check the console the web developer console in your browser

Comment: I receive a `cannot POST`

Comment: @KyleUSA Check my update now. I have vastly simplified it but it should help with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Apologies... maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have attached a mockup of what is happening vs what I would like to be the desired result. Any thoughts?